# Scheme: using backtracking to find sentence permutations given chars list and words list

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket, backtracking

Given `chars` - a list of characters and `words` - and list of words. I wish to find all possible permutations of sentences from given `words` list that use all `chars`.

For example:

`chars = '(i l o v e t e l e v i s i o n)`

`words = '((i) (l o v e) (v i s i o n) (t e l e) (t e l e v i s i o n))`

So running `(find-permutations '(i l o v e t e l e v i s i o n) '((i) (l o v e) (v i s i o n) (t e l e) (t e l e v i s i o n)))` will yield the following result:

`(((i) (l o v e) (t e l e) (v i s i o n))
 ((i) (l o v e) (t e l e v i s i o n)))`

I wrote the following code using Scheme language:

```
(define (substr sub str)
  (cond ((null? sub) str)
        ((null? str) #f)
        ((eq? (car sub) (car str)) (substr (cdr sub) (cdr str)))
        (else #f)))

(define (find-permutations chars words)

  (define (helper chars words1 result)
    (cond ((null? chars) (reverse result))
          ((null? words1) null)
          ((eq? chars #f) #f)
          (else (let* (
                       (x (substr (car words1) chars))
                       (y (helper x words (cons (car words1) result)))
                       (w (helper chars (cdr words1) result))
                       )
                  (if x
                      (cons y w)
                      w)
                  )
                )

          )
    )

  (trace helper)
  (helper chars words ())
  )
```

but i got too many brackets:
`((((((i) (l o v e) (t e l e) (v i s i o n))) ((i) (l o v e) (t e l e v i s i o n)))))`

I can't find why. Can anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `append` rather than `cons`

```
(define (substr? sub str)
  (cond ((null? sub) str)
        ((null? str) #f)
        ((eq? (car sub) (car str)) (substr? (cdr sub) (cdr str)))
        (else #f)))

(define (find-permutations chars words)
  (define (helper chars words1 result)
    (cond ((null? chars)  (reverse result))
          ((null? words1) #nil)
          ((eq? chars #f) #f)
          (else (let* ((chars-substr? (substr?
                           (car words1) chars))
                       (head (helper chars-substr? words (cons (car words1) result)))
                       (tails (helper chars (cdr words1) result)))
                  (if chars-substr?
                      (append head tails)
                      tails)))))

  (helper chars words '()))
```

When you `cons` together two lists as you did in your final predicate (`cons x y`), you are creating a "nested" structure by assigning your new results to a deeper and deeper chain of `car` pointers.

You might not notice this subtle difference because convention dictates omitting the 'true' structure of an S-expression list because the `car` cell is where associated list data is typically held.

The following diagram shows the list `(1 . (2 . (3 . (4 . ())`, which would be printed as `(1 2 3 4)` because of this convention.

[image: basic cons cell list]

Conversely, when `car` holds another list (rather than a value like `1`), it frequently represents a hierarchical structure, which is formatted with multiple enclosing parenthesis.